# Cross Page Postback with ListView

Tags: asp.net

I have a Source and Target page.  The Source.aspx uses a button to submit a search to the Target.aspx.  The browser address bar shows the postback occurred by showing ResultsTest.aspx?RecipeName=First+Full+Test.  The actual search will also post to the target page in a Label,  if a Label is used as (below is target .cs)

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((Request.QueryString["RecipeName"] != null))
        {

            Label1.Text = Request.QueryString["RecipeName"].ToString();  

        }

    }
```

But, in order for the posting to happen, the Label must be outside the ListView on the page.  The ListView has all the fields I would like to retrieve data for, and the Sql Select works as I have checked it in the Query Builder/Designer.  If the Page_Load is changed to a Label inside the ListView, from Label 1 to Label2 for example, an error message that the Label does not exist in the current context is displayed.

How can I get the ListView to accept the postback and retrieve the data and display on the target page?

EDIT:  For brevity sake, I removed some fields from the below ListView.  However, the point is, if I change the Page_load to read  the label ID of "labRecipeName" the "not in context" error shows up.  If I put the same label "outside" the list view, the postback happens and displays on the target page. What I want to do is make an entry on the source page and have it postback to the target page - which does happen. I cannot get the ListView to actually accept the query word and retrieve the data.

```
 <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="RecipeID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">

        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#  Bind("RecipeID", "ResultsTest.aspx?RecipeId={0}") %>'
                        Text='<%# Eval("RecipeName") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                    <asp:Label ID="labRecipeName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RecipeName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="width: 500px">
                <td>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<asp:LinkButton
                runat="server" ID="SortByName" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="RecipeName">Sort By Recipe Name</asp:LinkButton>
            &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="SortByPrice" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="RatingAVG">Sort By Rating</asp:LinkButton>
            <table id="Table1" runat="server">
                <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                    <td id="Td1" runat="server">
                        <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                            <tr id="Tr2" runat="server" style="">
                                <th id="Th1" runat="server">
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">

                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="Tr3" runat="server">
                    <td id="Td2" runat="server" style="" align="center">
                        <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager2" PagedControlID="ListView1" PageSize="8" runat="server">
                            <Fields>
                                <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonCount="8" />
                            </Fields>
                        </asp:DataPager>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RecipeUploadConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT pr.RecipeID, pr.CategoryName, pr.CategoryType, pr.RecipeName, pr.Description, COUNT(rr.RecipeID) AS Count, AVG(rr.Rating) 
        AS RatingAVG 
        FROM PostedRecipes AS pr LEFT OUTER JOIN RecipeRatings AS rr ON pr.RecipeID = rr.RecipeID 
        WHERE pr.RecipeName LIKE '%' + @RecipeName + '%' OR pr.CategoryName LIKE '%' + @CategoryName + '%' 
        OR pr.CategoryType LIKE '%' + @CategoryType + '%' OR pr.CuisineOrigin LIKE '%' + @CuisineOrigin + '%' 
        OR pr.CuisineType LIKE '%' + @CuisineType + '%'  GROUP BY pr.RecipeID, pr.RecipeName, pr.CategoryName, pr.CategoryType, pr.CuisineOrigin, 
        pr.CuisineType, pr.Description">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:FormParameter FormField="RecipeName" Name="RecipeName" Type="String" />
            <asp:FormParameter FormField="CategoryName" Name="CategoryName" Type="String" />
            <asp:FormParameter FormField="CategoryType" Name="CategoryType" Type="String" />
            <asp:FormParameter FormField="CuisineOrigin" Name="CuisineOrigin" Type="String" />
            <asp:FormParameter FormField="CuisineType" Name="CuisineType" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

EDIT:

Target Page .cs:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Configuration;
  using System.Data;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.Security;
 using System.Web.UI;
 using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Web.SessionState;

 namespace RecipeFaire
 {
 public partial class ResultsTest : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((Request.QueryString["RecipeName"] != null))
        {

            labRecipeName.Text = Request.QueryString["RecipeName"].ToString();  

        }

    }
   }
 }
```

Source Page .cs:

```
 using System;
 using System.Configuration;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.Security;
 using System.Web.UI;
 using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;



 namespace RecipeFaire
 {
 public partial class Search : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string targetURL;

        targetURL = "ResultsTest.aspx?";

        targetURL += "RecipeName=" + Server.UrlEncode(txtRecipeName.Text.Trim());

        Response.Redirect(targetURL);
    }
 }
}
```

EDIT

What I need to do is type "xxx" into a text box on the Source.aspx, have "xxx" post to Target.aspx as a search and to execute that search in a ListView contained in/on the Target.aspx.  I have verified, per the above description, that the cross page postback does happen.  I have verified that the Sql Select query does work.  So, it appears that my problem is not in the postback nor in the query.  However, with the Target.aspx.cs given above (except change the Label1 to labRecipeName to conformed to the following code) when "labRecipeName" is used "inside" (as an item) of the ListView, when the postback is attempted by entering "xxx", the error message "labRecipeName not in current context" appears.  If I move the "labRecipeName" outside of the ListView, but still on the Target.aspx, the error message goes away and the "xxx" appears as text on the Target page.  My problem is: How do I have the "xxx" go to an item, labRecipeName for example, inside the ListView in order to initiate a query and have the results of the query appear within the ListView? It may be that I have a total incorrect idea as how this end result should be achieved.  If so, I would appreciate any guidance on what I should be doing.

```
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#  Bind("RecipeID", "ResultsTest.aspx?RecipeId={0}") %>'
                    Text='<%# Eval("RecipeName") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                <asp:Label ID="labRecipeName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RecipeName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="width: 500px">
            <td>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
        &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<asp:LinkButton
            runat="server" ID="SortByName" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="RecipeName">Sort By Recipe Name</asp:LinkButton>
        &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="SortByPrice" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="RatingAVG">Sort By Rating</asp:LinkButton>
        <table id="Table1" runat="server">
            <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                <td id="Td1" runat="server">
                    <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                        <tr id="Tr2" runat="server" style="">
                            <th id="Th1" runat="server">
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">

                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Tr3" runat="server">
                <td id="Td2" runat="server" style="" align="center">
                    <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager2" PagedControlID="ListView1" PageSize="8" runat="server">
                        <Fields>
                            <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonCount="8" />
                        </Fields>
                    </asp:DataPager>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:ListView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RecipeUploadConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT pr.RecipeID, pr.CategoryName, pr.CategoryType, pr.RecipeName, pr.Description, COUNT(rr.RecipeID) AS Count, AVG(rr.Rating) 
    AS RatingAVG 
    FROM PostedRecipes AS pr LEFT OUTER JOIN RecipeRatings AS rr ON pr.RecipeID = rr.RecipeID 
    WHERE pr.RecipeName LIKE '%' + @RecipeName + '%' OR pr.CategoryName LIKE '%' + @CategoryName + '%' 
    OR pr.CategoryType LIKE '%' + @CategoryType + '%' OR pr.CuisineOrigin LIKE '%' + @CuisineOrigin + '%' 
    OR pr.CuisineType LIKE '%' + @CuisineType + '%'  GROUP BY pr.RecipeID, pr.RecipeName, pr.CategoryName, pr.CategoryType, pr.CuisineOrigin, 
    pr.CuisineType, pr.Description">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:FormParameter FormField="RecipeName" Name="RecipeName" Type="String" />
        <asp:FormParameter FormField="CategoryName" Name="CategoryName" Type="String" />
        <asp:FormParameter FormField="CategoryType" Name="CategoryType" Type="String" />
        <asp:FormParameter FormField="CuisineOrigin" Name="CuisineOrigin" Type="String" />
        <asp:FormParameter FormField="CuisineType" Name="CuisineType" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```